# Take audio from microphone, down sample it, encode it (using AAC) and transmit it via socket

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioengine

For the past few weeks, I've ben trying to hobble together a solution from a number of different examples which will allow me to:

1. Capture the audio from the microphone
2. Down-sample it to 8khz
3. Encode each buffer using AAC
4. Send the result out via a socket

Almost all the examples I've seen deal with encoding the audio to a file, which I do, for testing, but isn't what I need. I need to take a packet of data, encode and transmit it

## `MicrophoneService`

This basically sets up a `AVAudioEngine` and attaches a `AVAudioMixerNode` to it, which downsamples the audio.

The result is then placed into a blocking queue (`AudioEncoderQueue`) so that encoding service can encode the buffer

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

// Base on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595444/avaudioengine-downsample-issue
// https://github.com/onmyway133/notes/issues/367

class MicrophoneService {

    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

    init() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredSampleRate(16000)
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }

        let engineInputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
        let bus = 0
        let engineInputNodeFormat = engineInputNode.outputFormat(forBus: bus)

        //engineInputNode.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 1024, format: engineInputNodeFormat) { (buffer, time) in
        //  AudioEncoderQueue.shared.put(buffer)
        //}

        let mixer = AVAudioMixerNode()
        audioEngine.attach(mixer)

        let mixerOutputFormat = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 8000, channels: 1)

        audioEngine.connect(engineInputNode, to: mixer, format: engineInputNodeFormat)
        audioEngine.connect(mixer, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: mixerOutputFormat)

        mixer.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 1024 * 4, format: mixerOutputFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, time: AVAudioTime) in
            AudioEncoderQueue.shared.put(buffer)
        }
    }

    func start() throws {
        stop()
        audioEngine.prepare()
        try audioEngine.start()
    }

    func stop() {
        audioEngine.stop()
    }

}
```

## `AudioEncoderService`

This basically pops the next audio packet from the encoding queue, encodes it and places it onto the transmission queue (`TransportQueue`)

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import Cadmus

class AudioEncoderService {

    fileprivate var stopped: Bool = false
    // This is for debuging     
    fileprivate let audioFile: AVAudioFile

    init() throws {
        // The audio file is used to ensure that I'm getting audio from the microphone
        // As well as test the hardware can receive the data through a seperate C program
        var url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        url.appendPathComponent("Test.aac", isDirectory: false)

        let settings: [String: Any] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(value: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: NSNumber(value: 8000),
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: NSNumber(value: 1),
            AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey: NSNumber(value: 16),
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: NSNumber(value: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue)
        ]
        audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: url, settings: settings)
    }

    func start() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            self.encodeAudio()
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        stopped = true
    }

    func encodeAudio() {
        repeat {
            do {
                if let buffer = AudioEncoderQueue.shared.take() {
                    // I normally write the buffer to the AVAudioFile here, but I've removed for brevity
                    let data = Data(bytes: encodedBuffer.data, count: Int(encodedBuffer.byteLength))
                    TransportQueue.shared.put(data)
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        } while !stopped
    }

    func encode(_ buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) throws -> AVAudioCompressedBuffer? {
        return try AudioUtilities.convertToAAC(from: buffer)
    }

    func toData(buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) -> Data {
        let audioBuffer = buffer.audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers
        return Data(bytes: audioBuffer.mData!, count: Int(audioBuffer.mDataByteSize))
    }

// Prevois downsampling attempt     
//  func resample(_ buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) throws -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
//      guard let pcmBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: resampleFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(resampleFormat.sampleRate * 2.0)) else { return nil }
//
//      let inputBlock: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
//          outStatus.pointee = AVAudioConverterInputStatus.haveData
//          return buffer
//      }
//
//      var error: NSError? = nil
//      resampleConverter.convert(to: pcmBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputBlock)
//
//      guard let resampleError = error else { return pcmBuffer }
//
//      throw resampleError
//  }

}
```

### `AudioUtilities`

This is where the audio buffer is encoded using AAC and converted to `Data`.  This is based on a number of SO posts and some tweaking

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360127/decode-aac-to-pcm-format-using-avaudioconverter-swift
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360127/decode-aac-to-pcm-format-using-avaudioconverter-swift

class AudioUtilities {

    static func AACFormat() -> AVAudioFormat? {

        var outDesc = AudioStreamBasicDescription(
            mSampleRate: 8000,
            mFormatID: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
            mFormatFlags: 0,
            mBytesPerPacket: 0,
            mFramesPerPacket: 0,
            mBytesPerFrame: 0,
            mChannelsPerFrame: 1,
            mBitsPerChannel: 0,
            mReserved: 0)

        let outFormat = AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: &outDesc)
        return outFormat
    }

    static var lpcmToAACConverter: AVAudioConverter! = nil

    static func convertToAAC(from buffer: AVAudioBuffer) throws -> AVAudioCompressedBuffer? {

        let outputFormat = AACFormat()
        //init converter once
        if lpcmToAACConverter == nil {
            let inputFormat = buffer.format

            lpcmToAACConverter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: outputFormat!)
            lpcmToAACConverter.bitRate = 8000
        }
        let outBuffer = AVAudioCompressedBuffer(format: outputFormat!,
                                                packetCapacity: 8,
                                                maximumPacketSize: lpcmToAACConverter.maximumOutputPacketSize)
                                                //maximumPacketSize: 768)

        try self.convert(withConverter: lpcmToAACConverter,
                                         from: buffer,
                                         to: outBuffer)

        return outBuffer
    }

    private static func convert(withConverter: AVAudioConverter, from sourceBuffer: AVAudioBuffer, to destinationBuffer: AVAudioBuffer) throws {
        // input each buffer only once
        var newBufferAvailable = true

        let inputBlock : AVAudioConverterInputBlock = {
            inNumPackets, outStatus in
            if newBufferAvailable {
                outStatus.pointee = .haveData
                newBufferAvailable = false
                return sourceBuffer
            } else {
                outStatus.pointee = .noDataNow
                return nil
            }
        }

        var outError: NSError? = nil
        let status = withConverter.convert(to: destinationBuffer, error: &outError, withInputFrom: inputBlock)

        switch status {
        case .haveData: break
        case .inputRanDry: print("Input run dry")
        case .endOfStream: print("End of stream")
        case .error: print("!! Error")
        @unknown default: break
        }

        guard let error = outError else {
            return
        }
        throw error
    }
}
```

## `TransportService`

This basically takes the data from the transport queue and sends it out via a socket.  Each data packet is proceeded by a custom header, which isn't included as it is irrelevant.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftSocket

class TransportService {

    fileprivate var stopped: Bool = false

    var socket: TCPClient?
    let config: DeviceConfiguration

    init(config: DeviceConfiguration) {
        self.config = config
    }

    func start() throws {
        stop()
        stopped = false
        socket = TCPClient(address: config.ipAddress, port: Int32(config.port))
        print("Connect to \(config.ipAddress) : \(config.port)")
        switch socket!.connect(timeout: 30) {
        case .success:
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                self.transportData()
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            socket = nil
            throw error
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        stopped = true
        socket?.close()
        socket = nil
    }

    func transportData() {
        guard let socket = socket else { return }

        let headerLength = MemoryLayout<SPECIAL_HEADER>.size
        var header = SPECIAL_HEADER()
        // Populate the header properties
        // ...
        header.header_length = Int32(headerLength)
        header.sample_rate = 8000

        var count = 0

        repeat {
            guard let data = TransportQueue.shared.take() else { return }
            guard data.count > 0 else { return }

            header.packet_sn = Int32(count)
            header.data_length = Int32(data.count)

            var headerData = Data(bytes: &header, count: headerLength)
            headerData.append(data)
            print("\(count); \(header.data_length); \(headerData.count)")
            let result = socket.send(data: headerData)
            switch result {
            case .success: break
            case .failure(let error):
                log(error: "\(error)")
                return
            }
            count += 1


            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
        } while !stopped
        print("!! Stopped")
    }

}
```

*nb:* I've tested the transmission service independently using a test file and extracting each from it, so I know this part works.  This is only included to complete the basic overall picture.

## The problem...

1. I keep getting `Input run dry` from my encoder, no matter how large I make the buffer in the `MicrophoneService`
2. There is no audio hear at the hardware end (again, I've tested the transmission workflow using a static file and it does work) (no I don't control the hardware, but I have test source code which can send a AAC file, frame by frame, using the `TransportService` to it which works)

## The requirement...

The audio MUST be 8khz, mono and encoded using AAC.

## The Question(s)...

Is this the right approach or is there another approach I should take, to capture the audio, down sample it and encode it?

Is there anything I can do to limit the number of occurrences of `Input ran dry` or should I not care?

Comment: Were you able to achieve the desired result?

Comment: @bobski Not using this approach - we ended up writing the audio packets from microphone to a audio file (encoded with AAC) and using a "file inspector" to read the individual AAC packets become available

Comment: Did you find another solution @bobski ?

Comment: @P1xelfehler found a solution at that time. But honestly I can't remember what it was. I just remember that one day I woke up and the code was running all of a sudden